# While Debug mode, its working perfectly but in release APK it gives error

Tags: android, react-native

I have developed a react-native app for internal usage. In the Debug mode, it's working without any error and gesture is also working fine. But in release APK with self-signed Keystore its shows some error. When the Drawer and tab components are called it stopped working.

```
  "name": "AnnaIndustry",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^2.0.0",
    "autoresponsive-react-native": "^1.0.9",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.1.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.5.1",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

These are the libraries I used in my code

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: Unfortunately, AnnaIndustry has stopped.
This is the error I got

Comment: review progurde file might issue in classes rename.

Comment: How can I Review that progurde file?